# Query to get path

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

I have a table with following data:

```
Source | Destination
-------------------
46      47
47      49
48      49
49      50
```

I want to write a sql which returns a path list
i.e. For 46,50 as input query should return 46,47,49,50 as output.

Comment: Why does it start with `46` and not `47`?, what would've happened if the input was `46,8`?, or `51`?

Comment: 46,8 shall give error or no path found or something. 51,- also wont be queried. Query will always be from to destination.

Comment: consider 46,47.. as IDs from table which maintains list of city names.

Comment: What happens if the start doesn't have a path to the destination?

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, you can use a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE) like so:

```
declare @table Table(child int, parent int)

insert into @table(child, parent)
Values  
    (46, 47),
    (47, 49),
    (48, 49),
    (49, 50)


declare @start int
set @start = 46
;

with t1(child, parent) as (
select child, parent from @table t2
where child = @start
union all
select t.child,t.parent
from @table as t
join t1 on t1.parent = t.child
)
select parent from t1
union
select child from @table
where child = @start
```

Here are the results for the above query:

```
(4 row(s) affected)
parent
-----------
46
47
49
50

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a WHILE LOOP (PSEUDO / UNTESTED); you might also try a recursive CTE.

```
--INPUT VARS
@path_begin int
@path_end int

--FUNCTION OR PROC
DECLRE @source int
DECLRE @destination int
DECLRE @path varchar(max)
SET @path = 'No Path Exists'

SELECT @source = source FROM table WHERE source = @path_begin
SELECT @destination = destination FROM table WHERE destination = @path_end

IF @source is not null AND @destination is not null
BEGIN
   SET @path = @source
   WHILE @source < @destination
   BEGIN
      SELECT @source = min(source) FROM table WHERE source > @source AND @source < destination
      SET @path = @path + ',' + @source
   END
   SET @path = @source + ',' + @destination
END

RETURN @path
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution above from Derek Greer regarding using a Common Table Expression is incorrect for several reasons.  Two simple ones are:

1. It does not answer the original question because the goal was to provide a start and end point but his solution only has a start point.
2. If the second row from the sample table (47, 49) is removed, it would eliminate any possible path from 47 to 50 and should return a null value.  Instead, the code provided provides an erroneous path (46, 47, 48, 49)

The solution below from tamago does not work either.  Try a few simple cases, including the (46, 50) example you requested in your question, and you'll see that it does not work.

The answer is that this is a classic problem in Computer Science called the Traveling Salesman Problem.  You can read more about it at Wikipedia at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem.

There are many algorithms already published on this subject.  The easiest one to implement is to search through all possible permutations, but that only works on small data sets due to the large number of possibilities.  More advanced algorithms take longer to implement, but can work on much larger data sets.

You could also consider searching for an approximate solution.  There are approximate algorithms which will work on much larger data sets, and while they will return a valid path, they might not find the shortest one.